# What's the maximum number of contacts I can have in Microsoft Outlook 2019 (offline Desktop version for Windows 10 , 64 bit)?

Tags: outlook

What is the maximum number of Contacts I can keep in Microsoft Outlook 2019?
I use the offline version on a desktop computer running Windows 10 (64 bit).

I read the maximum number of items allowed per folder is 100,000.
Suppose Contacts is a folder, does this mean the maximum number of people I can keep in Contacts, therefore is 100,000 people?

If I need to have say 500,000 contacts, what can I do?

Thanks

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/performance/performance-issues-if-too-many-items-or-folders

Answer (score 1):

> I read the maximum number of items allowed per folder is 100,000.

Contacts are also Outlook items as well as mail items in a folder. So, yes - the same numbers can be applied to contacts in Outlook.